# Someone has proposed an exact copy of an existing stackexchange site on Area 51 - how to stop that?

Tags: support, area-51

There's a proposal [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7080/exercise-and-fitness?referrer=kM5kVIslEZJXXXrT0S5BhA2) for an exact copy of an existing stackexchange site (http.answersonfitness.stackexchange.com).

Why?

How does this make sense?

What's the best way to stop this?

Thanks!

Comment: I've added a link to the existing site on that proposal.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to stop, because it's perfectly legal; see [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/)

This is what would happen if the proposal becomes a site:

> ###Q: What happens with existing Stack Exchange sites?

> We don’t want to harm any communities that have already successfully gotten off the ground. This harks back to our corporate goal:

> *Make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions.*

> Community is hard to build, and we want to work with you to preserve it if you’ve already done that with Stack Exchange. If we closed down or competed with the existing, successful Stack Exchange sites, that would conflict with our goals.

> 1. Existing Stack Exchange sites will be kept open, under existing rules, for at least three months, and at least one year if you have an active site (defined as ten or more active users per day).
>    2. You will not have to pay for these sites, ever.
>    3. We’ll give you at least 3 months notice before shutting down any site.
>    4. We’ll always make your data available for download.
>    5. If your site remains very active, we’d love to work with you to migrate it to the new, community-owned Stack Exchange platform. That would be the best thing that could happen to a Stack Exchange 1.0 site, in our opinion: that way your site can take advantage of our existing resources and expansive community.

Comment: (-1) the question is about what to do if a proposal matches an existing site. Your answer, although interesting, is about what happens to the sites that already exist.

Comment: @dev, he's asking what would happen to a SE 1.0 if there's a proposal for the same topic. I believe I gave the correct answer.

Comment: *Clarification* - That's Joel's post (http://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) but I'm sure he wont take it personally.

Comment: @Rob, fearing his wrath, I edited that part out

Comment: @Rob That was my edit and fault, not Juan's